# Firefox Mac: pressing ⇧⌘N opens new window with strange URL?

Tags: macos, firefox, hotkeys

Using Firefox on OS X, the hotkeys for new window and private new window are <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Now I accidentally pressed <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, and to my surprise I got a new window (non private) with some strange URL already filled in: `http://www.isanalyze.com/watch?key=<long number>`

I'm rather concerned about this. What is this supposed to be? Do I have malware? Is <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> supposed to do anything?

More general, is there a way to find out what a certain hotkey combination is supposed to do at all?

Comment: cmd+shift+N is not a standard Firefox shortcut (http://www.7is7.com/software/firefox/shortcuts.html). Try starting with extensions disabled to see if that shortcut belongs to an extension.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments <kbd>⇧⌘N</kbd>, is not a standard/built-in shortcut.

A [quick Google](https://www.google.com.au/#q=www.isanalyze.com) of that URL implies that it's adware and generates annoying pop-ups.

I would start by checking any Firefox extensions you have installed. Start by selecting <kbd>Tools > Add Ons</kbd> and clicking on the `Plugins` tab. If anything there looks dubious turn it off and test the shortcut again.

Comment: `cmd+shift+N` is a standard shortcut (see mozilla support at [Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs). The standard shortcut performs `Undo Close Window`. However, as you say, a popup or extension may be opening a window and that's why `cmd+shift+N` shows it.